# Clipping from left rather than right when there isn't enough room for a child element?

Tags: wpf

I have a grid with three columns of width *, Auto, *.

When I collapse the grid width using an expander, I want the central column to remain fixed size.  I want the right hand column to begin clipping from the right hand edge.  This is the default behaviour, and already works fine.  However, I would like the first column to clip from the left-hand side.  That is to say, I'd like the left-hand edge of the column to become hidden first.  The left-hand column, is currently clipping from the right-hand edge.

Hope I've explained that well enough!  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to set HorizontalAlignment="Right" and ="Left" appropriately.

Here's an example, which may not match your requirements exactly, but clips from left and right as you require:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>


    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="Left hand column" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
    <Rectangle Grid.Column="1" Fill="Blue" Width="100"/>
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="Right hand column" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
    <GridSplitter Grid.Column="3" Width="4" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" ResizeBehavior="PreviousAndNext"/>
    <Rectangle Grid.Column="4" Fill="Red"/>
</Grid>
```